# vuex unknown mutation type: Nativescript application

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

I am writing a vue.js Nativescript application. I want Vuex to manage the connection status of the mobile device

the code I have set up monitoring on the connection status and fires every time it changes, I want to set the vuex state when this happens

when I run the code on the emulator it detects the state change correctly but gives this error

```
[vuex] unknown mutation type: updateConnectionStatus
```

I assume that the code is not being executed from the correct place, but it does not complain about finding the store.

this is my app.js

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import router from "./router"
import store from './store/store';
import * as connectivity from "tns-core-modules/connectivity";

const httpModule = require("http");

Vue.prototype.$router = router
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

connectivity.startMonitoring((newConnectionType) => {
    console.log('monitoring')
    switch (newConnectionType) {
        case connectivity.connectionType.none:
            store.commit('updateConnectionStatus', 'false')
            console.log("No network connection available!");
            break;
        case connectivity.connectionType.wifi:
            store.commit('updateConnectionStatus', 'true')
            console.log("You are now on wifi!");
            break;
        case connectivity.connectionType.mobile:
            store.commit('updateConnectionStatus', 'true')
            console.log("You are now on a mobile data network!");
            break;
    }
});


new Vue({

    render: h => h('frame', [h(router['login'])]),
    store,

}).$start()
```

and my mutator looks like

```
const mutations = {
    updateConnectionStatus(state,{ status }) {
        // mutate state
        state.connectionStatus = status
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `updateConnectionStatus(state, status) { state.connectionStatus = status }`, since your payload is not an object?

Comment: I have tried that but still get the same error

Comment: Would you mind updating the question with the code you use to initiate store with mutations?